# Problem with derivation of $U_B=-\mu \cdot \vec{B}$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, work, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics

I'm trying to prove that $U_B=-\mu \cdot \vec{B}$, but I keep running into an annoying dead end in my proof (a note about the notation my course's instructor uses: $\mu$ = magnetic moment, $NIA \hat{n} = NI\vec{A}$):

I start the way these problems generally do, which is defining an apparatus:

[image]

I then define the forces as follows:
$$Force \ on \ right\ leg\ of\ loop: \vec{F}_R = I\vec{l} \times \vec{B}; \ \vec{l}_R = l\hat{k}; \ \vec{F}_R=IlB_0(\hat{k}\times (cos(\theta)\hat{i} + sin(\theta)\hat{j}))$$
$$\vec{F}_R = IlB_0(-sin(\theta)\hat{i} + cos(\theta)\hat{j})$$
It follows by similar logic, that:
$$\vec{F}_L = IlB_0(sin(\theta)\hat{i} - cos(\theta)\hat{j})$$
I will not go into my derivation of the force on the top and bottom legs because they do not contribute to the rotation of the overall loop.

Next, I declare that
$$Work\ on\ left\ leg: W_L = -\int_c\vec{F}_L \cdot \vec{ds}$$
Using an identity given to us by our prof: $\vec{ds} = dx\hat{i} + dy\hat{j} + dz\hat{k} = -rsin(\theta)d\theta\hat{i} + rcos(\theta)d\theta\hat{j} + dz\hat{k}$:
$$W_L = -\int_c\vec{F}_L \cdot (-rsin(\theta)d\theta\hat{i} + rcos(\theta)d\theta\hat{j} + dz\hat{k})$$
$$W_L = -\int_c IlB_0(sin(\theta)\hat{i} - cos(\theta)\hat{j}) \cdot (-rsin(\theta)d\theta\hat{i} + rcos(\theta)d\theta\hat{j} + dz\hat{k})$$
$$W_L = IlB_0 \int_0^{\phi_1}(sin^2(\theta) + cos^2(\theta))rd\theta = IlB_0r\phi_1$$
Then, substituting r = a/2 and l = a, I get to the conclusion that to rotate the left leg of the loop through an angle $\phi_1$, $W_L=\frac{IB_0a^2}{2}\phi_1$. By applying similar logic to the right leg:
$$W_R = -\int_c\vec{F}_R \cdot (-rsin(\theta)d\theta\hat{i} + rcos(\theta)d\theta\hat{j} + dz\hat{k})$$
$$W_R = -\int_c IlB_0(-sin(\theta)\hat{i} + cos(\theta)\hat{j}) \cdot (-rsin(\theta)d\theta\hat{i} + rcos(\theta)d\theta\hat{j} + dz\hat{k})$$
$$W_R = -IlB_0 \int_0^{\phi_1}(sin^2(\theta) + cos^2(\theta))rd\theta = -IlB_0r\phi_1$$
This yields the equation $W_R = -\frac{IB_0a^2}{2}\phi_1$. If I then sum the work done on the right leg and the left leg, I get $W_{total} = -\frac{IB_0a^2}{2}\phi_1 + \frac{IB_0a^2}{2}\phi_1 = 0$, which is obviously not right. We know from the equation $U=-\mu \cdot \vec{B}$ that the answer should be $Ia^2B_0cos(\phi_1)$, not $0$.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Literally any help.

Comment: For one thing, the "identity" from your prof looks like it's probably something that's meant to hold in cylindrical coordinates and assumes $dr=0$, so it is set up for a problem with a circular loop. It doesn't make sense to use that identity in your problem with a square loop because (a) you can't assume $dr=0$ and (b) an integral over a square would turn into a huge mess in cylindrical coordinates. Additionally, there seems to be a minus sign error in your derivation of $W_L$. At least the last line should read $W_L=-Il B_0 r \phi_1$ given the equation before.

Comment: @Andrew I fixed the minus sign you mentioned -- that was an issue with the line before, not the result, so the conclusion at the end is unaffected, but thank you for the note regardless. Regarding what you said about cylindrical coordinates and square loops, I'm not too sure it matters that the loop is square because we're rotating it about an axis that's parallel to its surface, thus dealing with circular motion...I guess what I'm trying to say is that the "identity" is not being applied to the square, but the square's motion, which is, in fact, circular and thus the identity is applicable

Comment: OK I think I see what you mean... in other words, you are computing the work done in order to rotate the loop by an angle $\phi_1$ about an axis. Which axis? I'm also not sure I believe your expression for the work. The normal derivation uses the torque exerted on a current loop... see eg https://www.phys.ufl.edu/~acosta/phy2061/lectures/MagneticDipoles.pdf

Comment: @Andrew oh my god this is exactly the resource I've been looking for this whole time and couldn't find for the life of me. Thank you!!!